# Nuget from VSCODE is looking in the wrong place

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, nuget, azure-functions, nuget-package-restore

I am hitting an error with creating a new c# Azure Functions project in VSCode. The project generates fine but when I try to build and run, the nuget package manager is looking in the wrong place, it's looking for Azure packages in a private Azure DevOps package repo.

I saw a post suggesting I add a `nuget.config` to the project root (at the .csproj level) but this does not help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <packageSources>
    <add key="ArtifactoryNuGetV3" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
 </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas? Below is the error, it is clearly looking in the wrong place. The MYCUSTOMER package source is registered in my Visual Studio 2019, but is nowhere near the VSCode project, I assume there is some global setting fouling things up somewhere but I cant find it.

> Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
>   The content at
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'
>   is not valid XML.
>       For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on
>   XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create
>   method.   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
>   The content at
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'
>   is not valid XML.
>       For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on
>   XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create
>   method.   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
>   The content at
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'
>   is not valid XML.
>       For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on
>   XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create
>   method.   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
>   The content at
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'
>   is not valid XML.
>       For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on
>   XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create
>   method.   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
>   The content at
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'
>   is not valid XML.
>       For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on
>   XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create
>   method.   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
>   The content at
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'
>   is not valid XML.
>       For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on
>   XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create
>   method. C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.102\NuGet.targets(123,5):
>   error : Failed to retrieve information about
>   'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage' from remote source
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
>   [c:\dev\DuroFunc\DuroFunc.csproj] C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.102\NuGet.targets(123,5): error :   The content
>   at
>   'https://dev.azure.com/MYCUSTOMER-dev/MyCust.Packages/_packaging?_a=connect&feed=MyCust.Packages.Backend/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'
>   is not valid XML. [c:\dev\DuroFunc\DuroFunc.csproj] C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.102\NuGet.targets(123,5): error :   For security
>   reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD
>   processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to
>   Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
>   [c:\dev\DuroFunc\DuroFunc.csproj] Done: 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I got something like this and spent a while hunting it down.

Just after I upgraded my desktop VS2017 -> VS2019 and .Net Core 2.1 -> 3.1, but that may not be relevant.

I cleared the NuGet cache with

`dotnet nuget locals --clear all`

NuGet got a bit confused after that, so I restored packages, cleaned and built the solution and it's flying.

This helped: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/13366

HTH